# Channel Form: Why is Wygwam/CKFinder disabling the file browser for security reasons?

Tags: safecracker, pixelandtonic, wygwam, security

EE 2.9.2 - WYGWAM 3.3.3

In a Channel Form, I am getting the error...

> "The file browser is disabled for security reasons. Please contact
>   your system administrator and check the CKFinder configuration file."

...when trying to link to or upload a file.

In the Control Panel, Wygwam is working fine and the above scenario plays out as expected (works)

Yes, the Wygwam configuration setting is pointing to a proper directory.
Yes, we've added an XID hash to the form.

What else should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This just in from Brad at P&T:

> From what I can tell, if Admin->Security & Privacy->Security &
>   Settings's "Website Session Type" is set to anything with session in
>   it (session only, cookies and session), then EE just won't log you in
>   from the front-end of the site at all. No idea why.
>
> It will only work with "cookies only" selected. If EE were to log you
>   in on the front-end with sessions, then it would automatically start
>   the PHP $_SESSION global. Where Wygwam runs into trouble is that it
>   sees that $_SESSION hasn't been started so it calls session_start(),
>   but for some reason, EE sets that to a path restriction of {segment_2}
>   causing Wygwam not to able to read/write to it.
>
> However, if you go to Admin->Security & Privacy->Cookie Settings and
>   explicitly set the "Cookie Path" to "/", then it will save the cookie
>   with no path restriction and all of the sudden, CKFinder works like it
>   should on the front-end.

I don't know if this fits the definition of an Expression Engine bug, but it sure is hinkey.